# using a for loop variable as input for a dataframe name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe constructed as follows:

`df = pd.DataFrame({"taxon":["taxa1","taxa2","taxa3","taxa4","taxa5"],"rank":["genus","genus","family","species","species"]})`

There are 3 different ranks in this example dataframe: `genus`, `family` and `species`. I want to extract the rows of `df` to create new dataframes for each of the ranks with the corresponding rows of that rank. The name of the new dataframe should be `df_` followed by the name of the `rank`

So as **output** I want 3 dataframes `df_genus`, `df_family`, and `df_species`. Each of these contains the rows of that `rank` with the corresponding rows of the original `df` data frame.

I already tried several things, including:

```
ranks = ["genus","family","species"] 
for rank in ranks:
    "df_"+str(rank) = df.loc[df["rank"]==rank]
```

but this returns error: `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`

How can I perform this operation?

Comment: Use a `dict`, with keys `df_genus`, `df_family` and `df_species`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Use `d = {f'df_{k}': v for k, v in df.groupby('rank')}` and access like `d['df_genus']` etc. It's not a good idea to try and create variable names dynamically. see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `globals()` in order to create a dataframe inside a loop.

```js
ranks = ["genus","family","species"] 
for rank in ranks:
    globals()["df_"+str(rank)] = df.loc[df["rank"]==rank]
```

Hope it helps :)